# Why when accessing some wordpress pages on my localhost setup do i get the localhost default page?

Tags: xampp

why is that when accessing some pages(like [wp_login_form]) i get the default page for my localhost setup?  im running latest wordpress(default, no plugins mods etc) on latest xampp setup.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file within your WordPress root directory?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here: have you tried to add /index.php to the end of the URL for the page, e.g. hit

http://127.0.0.1:80/wp-admin/index.php

instead of just

http://127.0.0.1:80/wp-admin/

Not necessarily a solution, but might narrow down the problem a bit if this fixes it for you.

Comment: well im not talking about logging into admin, im talking about members logging into their accounts